# Standard procedure for confirming email for a web app

Tags: php, email

I have created a web app that is almost finished. I need it to confirm new emails. I just want to know if the these are the right procedures for that, because I'm not familiar with this.

I create a new table called "confirmEmails" with only one column with uniqueId. A unique Id is created with PHP: `uniqueid()` which is created directly after a user hit the submit button. And the php script stores it on the table. An email is sent together with a link www.domain.com/confirmEmail.php?uniqueId=kushfpuhrufhufhfhuhfheriufhehu. I have an another php script called confirmEmail.php that gets the value if uniqueId through the link with $_GET['uniqueId'];(maybe I shall use post instead her). And now it stores the new email in table called user

Is it right procedures? Pls give me some feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description says that you have only one column in your unique table. You need to associate the unique Id (token) with the specific user you validate. Otherwise a user could confirm a fake address using another user's unique id.

You could put the unique id in a column of the user table to make sure the right unique id used for activating an account.

Note: Another way would be to create a activation token from the user id and some secret in your configuration, such as `sha1($userid . 'yourSecret')`. With that you would not need to store additional data, but it is not possible to guess this token without knowing your secret.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like it would work fine. Seems like the standard now a days.

Comment: or maybe I shall use a sha1 hash instead to make it more secure?

Comment: @Woho87, how would you expect sha1 to increase security?